# How to make Database insertion failsafe in android?

Tags: android, mysql, http

The above code inserts multiple rows in a Mysql table. I want to make it fail proof,ie if the connection gets down in between insertion, how to roll back everything?

```
   for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i += 4) {
            ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
            item_id = Integer.parseInt(items.get(i));
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(items.get(i + 3));
            itemTotPrice = (BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(items
                    .get(i + 2)))).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(quantity));
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("order_id", String
                    .valueOf(order_id)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item_id", String
                    .valueOf(item_id)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", String
                    .valueOf(quantity)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("totalAmount", String
                    .valueOf(itemTotPrice)));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            try {
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    BillSummary.this,
                                    "Your order is placed. We will call you soon for confirmation!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Intent i = new Intent(BillSummary.this,
                                    OrderSummary.class);
                            i.putExtra("address1", address1);
                            i.putExtra("address2", address2);
                            i.putExtra("amount", tvTotalBill.getText()
                                    .toString());
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                } else {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(BillSummary.this,
                                    "No Internet Connection!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(
                                BillSummary.this,
                                "Connection Timed Out.Problem with the network!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

The above code inserts multiple rows in a Mysql table. I want to make it fail proof,ie if the connection gets down in between insertion, how to roll back everything?

Comment: add 3 requests to your database, one that starts a transaction, one that commits, and one that rollbacks.

Comment: as each row is inserted using different execute methods,every insertion is independent of the other...so how can I commit or rollback on failure?

Comment: can you put all your queries in one http post? that would make more sense, as http handles more easily atomic operations